# Почему в рамках темы "коммуникация между сервисами" часто противопосталяют протоколы HTTP (как синхронный) и AMQP (как асинхронный)?

Tags: веб-программирование, http, асинхронность, микросервисы, messaging

Почему в рамках темы "коммуникация между сервисами" часто противопосталяют протоколы HTTP (как синхронный) и AMQP (как асинхронный)? ([1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/communication-in-microservice-architecture), [2](https://greeeg.com/en/issues/microservices-patterns-synchronous-vs-asynchronous), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50454109/communication-between-microservices-request-data?rq=1), [4](https://www.theserverside.com/answer/Synchronous-vs-asynchronous-microservices-communication-patterns#:%7E:text=There%20are%20three%20ways%20to,hybrid%2C%20which%20supports%20both.))
С брокерами и AMQP понятно почему это асинхронно. Почему HTTP обычно представляют как синхронный способ, хотя можно сделать HTTP запрос асинхронно без ожидания ответа потоком? С моей точки зрения, он может быть как способом синхронной так и асинхронной коммуникации.

Возможно вспоминаю детали реализации веб сервера, но казалось что HTTP запросы при обработке тоже в очередь идут(не очень большую и только в оперативной памяти) на каком-то уровне, очередь не большая и если выходим за лимит, то теряем запросы. Скорее всего это в сам протокол не входит.

Comment: В данном случае асинхронность не относится к потокам или чему то еще такому. При синхронном общении, вы ожидаете ответ сейчас. Например, вы вызваете сервис, отпрвляете HTTP запрос и ожидаете, что будет ответ и он будет в разумное время. Это как по телефону позвонить - вы что то спршиваете и получаете сразу ответ. При асинхронной модели вы не ждете ответа вообще - если надо будет, он придет, если не надо - не придет. Это как емейл написать - вы пишете емейл, а кто и когда его прочитает и ответит ли вообще на него - это вопрос. Вы не ждете ответа вообще в этом случае.  Вот и вся разница.

Comment: Хоть и не сильно вникал в AMQP для сравнения, но вашу идею похоже понял. То есть не важно что HTTP можем использовать тоже подходом fire-and-forget(one-way) и отдавать 204 в респонсе чисто для отмашки, в любом случае протокол подразумевате что тот кто вызвал "ожидает" ответ, хотя может на самом деле это и не так в конкретной реализации на стороне отправителя запроса. А концепция с брокерами вообще не подразумевает обратного ответа, который можно ожидать, хотя в реализациях может быть (к примеру acks в кафке). Как вывод в статьсях рассматривают высокоуровнево протоколы без деталей.

Comment: да, по сути, когда говорят о синхронном или асинхронном взаимодействии сервисов, сам протокол не важен вообще. Важно только то, расчитываете вы получить ответ на ваш звпрос или нет. Если говорить про протоколы, а не сервисы, то HTTP построен так, что он подразумевает схему запрос-ответ, потому его называют синхронным, не смотря на то, что вы можете что то отсылать и не ждать ответа - ответ все равно будет куда то послан. AMQP же подразумевает не запрос-ответ, а обмен сообщениями. Типа как SMTP для почты позволяет отправлять сообщения.

Comment: Ещё раз заикнусь про сервисы. Вот, например, если вы отправляете комментарий на этом сайте - вы видите результат сразу, принят сервером комментарий или нет (если не принят, увидите текст ошибки). Это синхронное взаимодействие. Но вот если вы грузите видео на Ютуб, Ютуб это видео принимает и начинает обрабатывать и когда Ютубу надо будет, тогда он и закончит обработку видео. Например, если все люди на свете навалятся и будут отправлять видосы на обработку каждую минуту - это не положит сервис обработки видео, так как этот сервис просто поставит очень много задач на обработку в очередь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае асинхронность не относится к потокам или чему то еще такому. При синхронном общении, вы ожидаете ответ сейчас. Например, вы вызваете сервис, отпрвляете HTTP запрос и ожидаете, что будет ответ и он будет в разумное время. Это как по телефону позвонить - вы что то спршиваете и получаете сразу ответ. При асинхронной модели вы не ждете ответа вообще - если надо будет, он придет, если не надо - не придет. Это как емейл написать - вы пишете емейл, а кто и когда его прочитает и ответит ли вообще на него - это вопрос. Вы не ждете ответа вообще в этом случае. Вот и вся разница.

По сути, когда говорят о синхронном или асинхронном взаимодействии сервисов, сам протокол не важен вообще. Важно только то, расчитываете вы получить ответ на ваш звпрос или нет. Если говорить про протоколы, а не сервисы, то HTTP построен так, что он подразумевает схему запрос-ответ, потому его называют синхронным, не смотря на то, что вы можете что то отсылать и не ждать ответа - ответ все равно будет куда то послан. AMQP же подразумевает не запрос-ответ, а обмен сообщениями. Типа как SMTP для почты позволяет отправлять сообщения.

Ещё раз заикнусь про сервисы. Вот, например, если вы отправляете комментарий на этом сайте - вы видите результат сразу, принят сервером комментарий или нет (если не принят, увидите текст ошибки). Это синхронное взаимодействие. Но вот если вы грузите видео на Ютуб, Ютуб это видео принимает и начинает обрабатывать и когда Ютубу надо будет, тогда он и закончит обработку видео. Например, если все люди на свете навалятся и будут отправлять видосы на обработку каждую минуту - это не положит сервис обработки видео, так как этот сервис просто поставит очень много задач на обработку в очередь.